# trouble using autofs with ntfs-3g

Tags: linux, ntfs, ntfs-3g, autofs

I try to mount a ntfs disk with a `autofs` rule.
here is the slave file:

```
# cat /etc/autofs/auto.windows
# automount second disk which contains windows data
/windows        -fstype=ntfs-3g,uid=n0t,gid=n0t,nofail,users    :/dev/sdb2
```

and the concerning line in `auto.master`:

```
# cat /etc/autofs/auto.master
[...]
/-      /etc/autofs/auto.windows
[...]
```

I'm running `Archlinux` and this is what I get from `systemd`:

```
Aug 30 15:47:51 n0tlocal systemd[1]: Stopping Automounts filesystems on demand...
-- Subject: Unit autofs.service has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit autofs.service has begun shutting down.
Aug 30 15:47:52 n0tlocal systemd[1]: Starting Automounts filesystems on demand...
-- Subject: Unit autofs.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit autofs.service has begun starting up.
Aug 30 15:47:52 n0tlocal automount[2359]: do_umount_autofs_direct: couldn't get ioctl fd for direct mount /windows
-- Subject: Unit autofs.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit autofs.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
```

However, when I try it manually, running this command :

```
# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /mnt
```

I've got a working well rw file system.

Comment: try to debug what's happening with `automount -dvf`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other answer, the autofs version (at least 5.0.7 and 5.0.8) have a bug. They add the `-s` flag, which is not supported by ntfs-3g.

If updating is not an option for you, then here is a dirty workaround. It replaces `/bin/ntfs-3g` with a wrapper script which just removes the `-s` flag and passes the other options to the real ntfs-3g.

First, create the file `/bin/ntfs-3g_wrapper` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTS=$(echo $@ | sed "s/-s/ /")

exec /bin/ntfs-3g_real $OPTS
```

Now make it executable, rename the real `ntfs-3g` to `ntfs-3g_real` and create a symlink from `ntfs-3g` to `ntfs-3g_wrapper`:

- `sudo chmod +x /bin/ntfs-3g_wrapper`
- `sudo mv /bin/ntfs-3g /bin/ntfs-3g_real`
- `sudo ln -s /bin/ntfs-3g_wrapper /bin/ntfs-3g`

I have successfully used this approach. Of course, it is a dirty solution. An update to the `ntfs-3g` package might for example replace your symlink with the new version of the `ntfs-3g` binary, and the problem is there again.

This answer is based on a [blog post by ScottE](https://scotte.org/2015/11/autofs-with-ntfs), thanks a lot, Scott.

Answer (score 0):

At least autofs 5.0.7 had a bug causing all ntfs-3g mounts to fail. Upgrade to 5.1.1.

The reason is "-s" option (SLOPPY) to mount command that should only be used with nfs.

```
/usr/sbin/automount -dvf
...
mount_mount: mount(generic): calling mount -t ntfs-3g -s -o utf8,uid=99,gid=99,umask=000 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/auto/usb2
>> ntfs-3g: Unknown option '-s'.
```